# Send data with in 2 android devices that connected to same network using there IP address?

Tags: android, wifi, data-transfer

More than a code I need a guidance. I want to make a app that transfer data via 2 android devices that connected to same network that using there IP address.
So can someone please help me that what areas I have to cover before start this or can someone give some example to follow ??

Comment: Search for "Android socket sample".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to to check [WIFI Peer to Peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html#creating-app), it allows two devices to connect to each other over wifi and share data. Sample code is available in the same link.

Comment: Hi @Karthik, have you worked on this kind of app, if yes, can you provide me sample.

Answer (score 0):

To send data in the LAN between two android devices connected in the same Network. You need sockets . [Android TCP/IP SOCKET Example](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2014/06/android-tcpip-client-server-socket.html)  .